# Why are the screws of the Macbook Pro blue on one side?

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro, warranty

I just bought a new early '12 Macbook Pro 13" and was about to open it to swap that pesky HDD with a fresh SSD. After lifting the first screw I saw that the screws are blue on one side.

I'm asking myself why they are like this. Is that
 a measurement to detect if the warranty has been voided?
If yes, how can I still replace the HDD without voiding the warranty 'further'

[image: Macbook Pro screw]

Comment: From what I've been told in the past it's also to check if the warranty has been voided.

Comment: Replacing a User Serviceable Part does not void your warranty, as Apple would not provide you instructions on how to do something that would void your warranty.  You can find instructions in your Macbook Pro manual http://support.apple.com/manuals/#macbookpro as to how you go about replacing your hard drive.  The Locktite used on those screws is to keep them from falling out on their own.  Yes, I know that screws don't normally do that, but the single drop of locktite is added insurance that they don't.  It is not a system by which they can avoid being held to the warranty.

Comment: I've also seen this on Acer and Dell laptops. It must be pretty common.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a threadlock. Or 'screwfix' as you may know it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-locking_fluid

Comment: So this alone won't void the warranty?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: I have always heard it called "Locktight" It is also used on vehicle bolts. For that matter it can be put on your own screws. It wouldn't be the greatest warranty voider in my humble opinion

Comment: This isn't something specific to Apple either, HP and Dell both use it and I'm sure many other manufacturers do as well, and not to detect if you've messed with the hardware, just to keep screws from shaking loose over time. Laptops move around a lot and due to fans, they vibrate, without locktight, eventually something would loosen up.

Comment: @steve Loctite is a registered trademark brand name. "Thread locking fluid" or "threadlocker" are acceptable generic terms.

Answer (score 3):

Apple use Blue Loctite on most of their screws to keep them in place and also so they can detect if they have been moved. (warranty)

Comment: And yet they're literally always falling out...